# Setting column widths of two tables

Tags: html, css

Can we adjust column width of a table by adjusting another table's column width?

Elaborately :

In my HTML I have thead part set inside another table tag and the rest of the part in another table tag so that column headers remain fixed while scrolling.

Now I want to adjust column widths by adjusting thead part i.e. column widths must be adjusted automatically when I adjust the thead in another table.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: It's a lot easier for people to answer questions like this if you include the relevant parts of your code. Can you post some?

Comment: If you put your code on a fiddle for us http://jsfiddle.net/ it makes it a lot easier to help you

Comment: <div><thead><table></table></thead></div>